# Google sheet Automation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets-api

Can you please help me, How to send dynamic mail every latest entry in google sheet?

```
function CustomEmail() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:C4");
var UserData = range.getValues();
for (i in UserData) {
var row = UserData[i];
var name = row[0];
var email = row[1];
var score = row[2];
MailApp.sendEmail(row[1], "Custom mail", "Hello " + name + ", This is an email report of your score. Your score is " + score);
}
}
```

Comment: Show us how your data is structured after hiding sensitive information, also please explain this `How to send dynamic mail every latest entry in google sheet`

Answer (score 0):

Setup a trigger in your project: Trigger for "form submission". Whenever someone submits the form, script will send out the email to those whom the email wasn't sent. Also have a helper column in the sheet to update status for the script to filter out the people who already received the email, else others will keep receiving their scores everytime there's a form submission.